# Formula for calculating FFmpeg Minrate, Maxrate, and Bufsize?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm looking for some kind of formula where I could put in the desired bitrate `-b:v` and have it calculate a good quality `-minrate`, `-maxrate`, and `-bufsize` for any video.

So if a video's original bitrate is `8M` `8000K`, and you want to convert it to `2M` `2000K`, what should the `min/max/buf` be?

Right now I have to guess and it always comes out pixelated unless I set the `-maxrate` and `-bufsize` really high.

---

Using `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.

---

### One-Pass / Two-Pass

**Desired (Pixelated)**

`ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -b:v 2M -minrate 1M -maxrate 2M -bufsize 2M output.mkv`

**High Quality (Min/Maxrate)**

`ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -b:v 2M -minrate 1M -maxrate 6M -bufsize 6M output.mkv`

**High Quality (No Min/Maxrate)**

`ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -b:v 2M output.mkv`

---

### CRF

I notice in `CRF` sets the `maxrate` almost as high as the original video's bitrate, then lowers it for frames that are not as complex. The video come out very high quality and low file size.

**Desired (Pixelated)**

`ffmpeg -y -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -minrate 1M -maxrate 2M -bufsize 2M output.mkv`

**High Quality**

`ffmpeg -y -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 20 output.mkv`

Comment: Don't use the input bitrate as a metric for comparison–it is essentially meaningless. What's the ultimate goal here? What's the reason for re-encoding in the first place? Why do you want to set these options?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard To reduce the file size of a video while maintaining quality. Sometimes re-encoding a 2,000K 2GB video with `-crf 24` can reduce it to 1GB and still look good. Using `-maxrate` can further reduce the file size.

Comment: Use VideoLogic, an FFMPEG wrapper I wrote that does so much of this for you.

Setting a maximum bitrate isn't controlling the maximum average bitrate -- it's telling the encoder to never peak above this, even if the average is well below. That means for slow scenes, the bitrate can dip below the average bitrate you've set, but it can never exceed it when the encoder hits high-complexity scenes, causing pixelation. That's why setting a higher maxrate is giving you better quality results, because it allows any scene to peak above the average as long as the whole video stays around the average.